# Mongocxx accessing Error from different cpp file

Tags: c++, mongodb, instance, mongo-cxx-driver, mongodb-c

I have created a header `mongo.h` it contain

```
mongocxx::instance inst{};
mongocxx::uri uri{ "link*****" };
mongocxx::client client{ uri };
```

i accessed the mongodb from `main.cpp` by including this
`mongo.h`
but when including this header to other cpp file it return error.

Documents saying that the instance must create once .
i have read http://mongocxx.org/api/current/classmongocxx_1_1instance.html
not understand fully, i dont familiar with constructor and destructor ,,
Any body please help to access mongodb from every cpp file .

Comment: ***it return error*** what error do you get? Please share a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of where a singleton could help.
In `mongo.h`, put a single function declaration:

```
mongocxx::client& get_client();
```

In a *single* cpp file, define the function as follows:

```
mongocxx::instance inst{};
mongocxx::client& get_client() {
  static mongocxx::client client{mongocxx::uri{ "link*****" };};
  return client;
}
```

By putting this in a separate .cpp file, you ensure that `inst` is created some time before the `main` function starts. The `static` keyword in `get_client` ensures that the client is only ever created once, namely the first time `get_client` is called.